# Reading and Printing a matrix

Tags: c

I tried to read and print a matrix using an external function (from another c file), the thing is that I want to read the matrix dimensions in the function and store them in the main function, how can I do this?

Do I need to return an array with the m and n dimensions of the matrix or can I access the variables that I created in main and change their value within the external function? (I prefer if someone would explain the second) I don't actually know how to use pointers and stuff.
Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker, also thanks for your response

The second and the third functions are in an external function.c file

```
int main(){

    int num_of_rows, num_of_columns;
    int matrix[10][10];
    

    read_matrix(num_of_rows, num_of_columns, matrix);
    
    print_matrix(num_of_rows, num_of_columns, matrix);
    

    printf("\n Press any key to exit the program: ");
    _getch();
    return 0;

}


void read_matrix(int num_of_rows, int num_of_columns, int matrix[10][10]){

    int i,j;
  

    printf("\nPlease specify the number of rows:");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_rows);
    printf("\nPlease specify the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_columns);
    
    printf("\nPlease introduce the matrix elements below:\n");
    for(i=0; i<num_of_rows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<num_of_columns; j++){
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]= ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


void print_matrix(int num_of_rows, int num_of_columns, int matrix[10][10]){

    int i,j;
   

    for(i=0; i<num_of_rows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<num_of_columns; j++){
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]= %d", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `num_of_rows` and `num_of_collums` (probably better spelled `num_of_columns`) are uninitialized when passed to `read_matrix()` — that is not a good start.  You can modify the values of the local variables in the `read_matrix()` function; that does not affect the values of the variables in the `main()` function.  You'd need to pass the variables as pointers — `&num_of_rows`, etc — and the function would need to expect pointers instead of plain `int`.

Comment: I'd try and encapsulate the matrix in a struct: `struct Matrix { size_t rows, cols; int *data; };`... then pass around and use a pointer: `struct Matrix *p;` ... `print_matrix(struct Matrix *p) { for (size_t row = 0; row < p->rows; row++) for (size_t col = 0; col < p->cols; col+) printf("%d ", p->data[row*p->cols + col]); }`

Comment: Wow , that is a great idea , I did not think about using structs , thx man :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters are passed by value in C.

In `read_matrix`, the `num_of_rows` parameter is a *local* variable.  Even if you modify it, the caller won't see anything change. Same for `num_of_columns`.

You want this:

```
void read_matrix(int *num_of_rows, int *num_of_columns, int matrix[10][10]) {
  //                 ^ add *           ^ add *
  ...
  scanf("%d", num_of_rows);    // << remove the &
  printf("\nPlease specify the number of columns: ");
  scanf("%d", num_of_columns); // << remove the &
  ...

  for (i = 0; i < *num_of_rows; i++) {
    //            ^add *
    for (j = 0; j < *num_of_columns; j++) {
      //            ^add *
```

and in `main`:

```
read_matrix(&num_of_rows, &num_of_columns, matrix);
//          ^             ^ add the &s
```

This is basic knowledge that is covered in your C learning material. Most likely in the chapter dealing with pointers and the one dealing with function calls.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the catch. I tested your code and it works nicely. The problem is, what you want to achieve is only possible by using **dynamic memory allocation**. Take a look at the **malloc** and **free** functions.

You can read more about it on:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-malloc-in-c-language
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-malloc-and-free-work-in-c-cplusplus

In C language you are responsible for allocation a space in memory for variable length data structures. Pointers just store an address to a specific memory space allocated to the desired data type.

e.g.:

```
int n, *p;
p = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

In this example, you are just giving p an address to the first integer from **n** integers you just allocated.

**p** will work just like a vector when using **for loops** because behind the scenes, it's exactly what happens when you traverse your fixed length vectors and matrices, but this time you were in control of it's length in runtime.

Comment: `The problem is, what you want to achieve is only possible by using dynamic memory allocation` couldn't be further from the truth.

Comment: @marco-a: If OP wants to use sizes entered by the user at run time that are not bounded by sizes fixed at compile time, then dynamic memory allocation is the only feasible solution. Automatic allocation is typically limited in C implementations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I somewhat agree with your stance. However, stating that `it's only possible with dynamic memory allocation` is not true.

Comment: I mainly downvoted because of `I tested your code and it works nicely.` @LeonardSandu your code is erroneous to begin with (see comment by Jonathan on your post).

Comment: As @EricPostpischil stated before. Automatic allocation is limited and I don't encourage it's use. For me, malloc, calloc and realoc are the way to go, always. But that's also an opinion all of my own as it gives more control over your own applications.

Comment: I used to like `malloc` and `free`, but the thing is: 1.) your resources are limited anyway. It doesn't matter whether you get that memory from stack or heap. There's always a limit. That limit maybe hard to reach on modern computers, but it's still there. Also, you also want to set a limit for the user input _anyway_ otherwise you risk a denial of service vulnerability. This might sound far fetched, and to some extend, it is. However, I strongly believe (especially beginners) should be taught what ways there are and not "this is the only way".

Comment: This isn't the reason I downvoted though, as previously mentioned, OP's code is erroneous to begin with. Hence I strongly disagree with `I tested your code and it works nicely.` - gives the OP a false sense of security: just because it ''works'' doesn't mean it's correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x[3][3], p, q, max;
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix: \n");
    for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
       for(q=0;q<3;q++)
       scanf("%d", &x[p][q]);
    }
    max=x[0][0];
    printf("The matrix is as follows: \n");
    for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
       for(q=0;q<=3;q++)
       scanf(" %d", &x[p][q]);
    }
    for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
        for(q=0;q<3;q++)
        {
            if(x[p][q]>max)
            max=x[p][q];
        }   
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    printf("Maximum number in the matrix is: %d", max);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the elements of matrix: 

23 65 12 
12 23 56
12 10 32

The matrix is as follows: 

23 65 12
12 23 56
12 10 32

Maximum number in the matrix is: 65
```

[Matrix Programs](https://codeforever.in/array-in-c-c-program/)

Explore more [matrix programs](https://codeforever.in/?s=matrix).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be all that closely related to the code in the question.  It doesn't use any of the functions which the original code uses.  It's a direct copy of one of the programs in the first link — I suppose that's credit given.  But you don't explain what was wrong in the code in the question or how this code addresses those problems, so it really isn't very helpful.